# How to remove duplicate rows based on a column (leaving first one out) in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to remove duplicates from my Google spreadsheet file.

Here is an initial table example

```
     A       B   C   D
HelloWorld1  2   6  41
HelloWorld1  4   3   5
HelloWorld2  6   46  6
HelloWorld2  2   4   4
HelloWorld2  5   6   2
HelloWorld3  9   3   5
```

It should remove all duplicates but leave the fist entry as follows:

```
     A       B   C   D
HelloWorld1  2   6  41
HelloWorld2  6   46  6
HelloWorld3  9   3   5
```

I have tried different formulas and techniques, however I haven't got them working.
Sorting is not suitable, because I need to leave the same order of rows.

I have tried the following formula for removing, based on the first column. However, I got `An array value could not be found`

```
 =ArrayFormula(vlookup(UNIQUE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(A:A,COUNT(A:A),1)),A:D,column(A:D),1))
```

which would be he correct formula? It would be great if this could be done in a single formula or query.

Comment: Please give a read to the [ask] page. It is also helpful when you include a link to a sample sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A:A),A:D,{1,2,3,4},FALSE)))`

Answer (score 0):

Today Google announced a built-in feature to remove duplicates.

From [Three new features to format and work with data in Sheets](https://gsuiteupdates.googleblog.com/2019/05/new-sheets-features-may.html)

> **What’s changing**
>
> We’re introducing three new features that will help you clean up and
>   work with your data in Sheets. These features are:
>
> - Remove duplicates
> - Trim whitespace
> - Compatible spreadsheet shortcuts

The move duplicates function is on the Data menu.

NOTE: I could take few days to get this feature.